# Why does Psiphon not use TAP-Windows but a local proxy to tunnel windows?

Tags: proxy, vpn

I use Psiphon.
The problem is that Psiphon does not tunnel all applications (especially those that do not support proxies).
Psiphon uses a local proxy, but why doesn't Psiphon use TAP-Windows instead ?
Cordially.

Sorry for my bad English.